# Will storage space of other operating system be affected?

Tags: dual-boot

I would like to convert Kubuntu into Xubuntu without redoing the whole PC.

I have also installed Windows on the same PC, so I fear that if I Download/Install Xubuntu, I might disturb Windows on my storage space. Will Xubuntu only use the storage space of Kubuntu or could it affect the Windows space?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu can be installed in place of Kubuntu. You'll be presented with an option to replace Kubuntu with Xubuntu in the installation phase. If that is not the case, you can always select the existing Kubuntu partition as the `/` for the new Xubuntu installation in manual partitioning. That will be OK.

Check the installation guide for more details.

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)